# Two path multivariable limit

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{9x-10y}{x^2+y^2}$$

For the path $\gamma_{1}(t)=(t^2,0)$, I got
$$\lim_{t\to0}f(\gamma_{1}(t))=\infty$$
while, for $\gamma_{2}(t)=(0,t^2)$, I found
$$\lim_{t\to0}f(\gamma_{2}(t))=-\infty$$

May I conclude then the limit itself doesn't exist? Or the value of the limits should be a real number?

Comment: yes you can conclude it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conclude that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes exactly once we find (at least) $2$ different limits for $2$ different paths we are done since, by the [uniqueness theorem of limit](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-uniqueness-of-limits-of-a-function-theorem),  we can conclude that limit doesn't exist.

It can be interesting to note that by polar coordinates we obtain

$$\frac{9x-10y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{9\cos \theta-10\sin \theta}{\rho}$$

from which we can find special paths which leads to a specific value for the limit, notably by

$$\theta = \arctan \left(\frac 9{10}\right)+k\rho$$

with $k\in\mathbb R$ we obtain

$$\frac{9\cos \theta-10\sin \theta}{\rho}=-k\sqrt{181}\frac{\sin(k\rho)}{k\rho}\to -k\sqrt{181}$$